# PHP how to limit file type condition like jpg, gif, png?

Tags: php

I would like to ask how do I limit the file type for PHP image upload? I would like to limit it to png, jpg and gif only. Sorry for this noob question.

What I have tried is to add 'OR' to the condition. But how come when I upload jpg,gif or png it doesn't work?

```
<?php 

//limit file type condition
if(!($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/png") 
|| !($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/jpg") 
|| !($_FILES["photo"]["type"] == "image/gif")){

echo "You may only upload png, jpg or gif.<br>";
$ok=0;
} 

?>
```

Comment: Why would it work if the file type is one of the ones you want?

Comment: @Anthony, i wanted to allow only png, jpg and gif. If the file is not one of them, then echo "You may only upload, png, jpg or gif.

Comment: You need to change the Or to And because you are checking that all three are *not* true, so all three must pass. So change || to &&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make this much shorter and more readable by using [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/in_array):

```
$allowed_extensions = array( "image/png", "image/jpg", "image/gif" );

if ( !in_array( $_FILES[ "photo" ][ "type" ], $allowed_extensions ) ){
  echo "You may only upload png, jpg or gif.<br>";
  $ok = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
$config['upload_path'] = '';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';       //pic type
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
   $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); //you will get error statement in $error
}
else
{....
}
```

Comment: It's an external library that the answer incorrectly assumes everyone is familiar with.